# Add icon inside cell in R

Tags: html, r, icons

I have two dataframes below. They are identical except of their values. What I want to do is compare each value of `DF1` with the relative value of `DF2` and then add an icon like an arrow which will be 'up' if `DF1` has bigger value and 'down' if `DF1` has smaller value than `DF2`.

```
FCB<-c(5,6,4,6,8)
TWI<-c(3,5,2,3,5)
IN<-c(2,1,1,1,1)
DF1<-data.frame(FCB,TWI,IN)

FCB<-c(0,0,1,2,4)
TWI<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
IN<-c(1,3,4,5,6)
DF2<-data.frame(FCB,TWI,IN)
```

Comment: You could probably use the html arrows found here: https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_arrows.asp within each cell

Comment: how should I add them in the same as there is already the value there

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sjPlot)

#Compering data.frames
compValues <- ifelse(DF2 - DF1 > 0, 
                         paste("<p>&#8593;</p>"), 
                         paste("<p>&#8595;</p>")) %>% 
      as.data.frame() %>% 
      varhandle::unfactor()

#Display as html
sjPlot::tab_df(compValues)
```

Output:

[image]

## Edit

There are easier/more readable ways to do that, but you can use a nested `ifelse`:

```
compValues <- ifelse(DF2 - DF1 > 0, 
                     paste("<p>&#8593;</p>"), 
                     ifelse(DF2 - DF1 < 0, 
                            paste("<p>&#8595;</p>"), 
                            paste("<p>&#8646;</p>"))) %>% 
                       as.data.frame() %>% 
                       varhandle::unfactor()

sjPlot::tab_df(compValues)
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: thats a good thought. Can I ask what to put when 2 values are the same?how can I put "="